# Filtering with multiple OR / AND in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first question here. I searched a lot off docs, but can't find answer.
I have 3 tables.

```
product_main(with idx and name)<br />
proudct_attributes (with idx 'pid gid value)<br />
product_attributes_groups (with idx name) <br />
```

Now I trying to filter products by attributes. I have no problem with single attribute, but I can't make it work to filter with several conditions i.e. (red or blue , but only new)

```
SELECT `pid` FROM `product_attributes`
LEFT JOIN `product_main` ON `product_attributes`.`pid` = `product_main`.`idx` 
LEFT JOIN `product_attributes_groups` ON `product_attributes`.`gid` = `product_attributes_groups`.`idx` 
WHERE
  (
   (`product_attributes_groups`.`name` = 'color' AND `product_attributes`.`value` ='red' )
   OR
   (`product_attributes_groups`.`name` = 'color' AND `product_attributes`.`value` ='blue' )
  )  
  AND
  (`product_attributes_groups`.`name` = 'condition' AND `product_attributes`.`value` ='new' )
```

EDIT:

This helped: 
select `pm`.`idx`
from `product_attributes` as `pa` join
     `product_main` as `pm`
     on `pa`.`pid` = `pm`.`idx` join
     `product_attributes_groups` as `pig`
     on `pa`.`gid` = `pig`.`idx` 
group by `pm`.`idx`
having sum(`pig`.`name` = 'color' AND `pa`.`value` in ('red' , 'blue')) > 0 and
       sum(`pig`.`name` = 'condition' AND `pa`.`value` ='used') > 0;

Answer by Gordon, with a little editing.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Is this EAV? Generally, I avoid EAV like the plague. Where I'm obliged to use it, I prefer to construct a pseudo-normalized 'materialized view' and then attach the desired conditions to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a "set-within-sets" query, where you are trying to find matches within a group (attributes on a product).  I like to solve these with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select pm.pid
from product_attributes pa join
     product_main pm
     on pa.`pid` = pm.`idx` join
     product_attributes_groups pig
     on pm.`gid` = `pig`.`idx` 
group by pm.pid
having sum(pig.`name` = 'color' AND `pa`.`value` in ('red' , 'blue')) > 0 and
       sum(pig.`name` = 'condition' AND pa.`value` ='new') > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is counting the number of rows for each `pid` that match one condition.

Answer (score 0):

A condition like

```
WHERE
    `product_attributes_groups`.`name` = "something"
    AND `product_attributes_groups`.`name` = "something else"
```

can never be true. Check what you're aiming to do and rewrite your filter.

Comment: I have multiple rows with different `product_attributes_groups`.`name` values, same with `product_attributes`.`value`  I want to select all products that are new, but may be blue or red.

Comment: Then you need to `JOIN` again on the same table, use an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It should work with the combination (name AND (red OR blue)) OR (condition AND new)

```
SELECT `pid` FROM `product_attributes`
LEFT JOIN `product_main` ON `product_attributes`.`pid` = `product_main`.`idx` 
LEFT JOIN `product_attributes_groups` ON `product_attributes`.`gid` = `product_attributes_groups`.`idx` 
WHERE
   (`product_attributes_groups`.`name` = 'color' AND (`product_attributes`.`value` ='red' OR `product_attributes`.`value` ='blue') )
  OR
  (`product_attributes_groups`.`name` = 'condition' AND `product_attributes`.`value` ='new' )
```

Comment: This returns all products, new and old. I want it to return only the new ones. Thx for help tho :)

Comment: @LordKarp . yes, that makes sense ;) Did you try this: (name AND (red OR blue)) AND (condition AND new). Although I like the elegant solution from GordonLinoff using HAVING